# SSIS: FTP task errors before file is created

Tags: ssis

I have a package I just started. FYI, I haven't worked in SSIS before, only DTS ages ago. But basically:

1. I have a `Data Flow Task` and an `FTP task`.
2. Inside the `Data Flow` there is an `OLE DB Source` and `Flat File Destination`

If I take out the `FTP task`, it creates the file fine and drops it into the folder. But with the FTP Task in place, it bombs saying the file isn't there (and it isn't) ***but it's not waiting for the file to be created*** before trying to FTP it. I have the `Precedence Constraint` set to 'Constraint' and 'Success' so it SHOULD wait, right?... What am I missing?

[image: ControlFlow]
[image: DataFlow]

Comment: I think the text file path not reading execution time. Better you can read the path from  using variable expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the DelayValidation property of FTP task to TRUE